# Capturing screen of "perf top" or other interactive programs

Tags: gnu-screen, perf

I'm trying to write a script to capture output of `perf top`

Similar to `top`, `perf top` detects the screen size and fill information to the screen. But sadly unlike `top` which has a batch mode, `perf` does not. So what I thought would be smart to do is to launch `perf top` using `screen -d -m` and get the output by calling `-X hardcopy`.

Actual command used to launch screen & perf top (Backtick substituted with single quote due to escape character):

`screen -S 'cat $session' -d -m perf top`

Strange thing happening here is that calling `screen -S 'cat $session' -X hardcopy` would yield an empty file. But once I have attached and detached from the screen, `-X hardcopy` would produce the expected output of `perf top`.

Any idea on how I can capture the output of `perf top` or working around the issue in `screen`? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain ([edit] your question) what you're trying to do with the captured output? Do `perf record` and `perf report` not give you the information you're after?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `perf record` only record metrics of a certain command? I'd like to capture `perf top` when system performance (measured using other scripts) meets some certain condition.

Comment: You can capture all the activity in a system with `-a`; for example `perf record -a sleep 5` records all the activity for five seconds. We're monitoring `sleep 5` but with everything else as well...

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I needed. Hope I could understand the man page better.